# Get PyCharm console working similar to in Eclipse?

Tags: python, pycharm

Something I miss from my days of using Eclipse and PyDev is the ability to launch the console and have all of the source folders added to the Python path. I could easily just import any of the modules/packages I was currently working on and play around with them.

So far I haven't figured out how to get this working in PyCharm. I'm sure it is there, but I haven't found it. Whenever I go to Tools/Run Python Console... it launches a console, but it doesn't have any of the source directories appended to the path. What do I have to do to get this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Under `options`, then `Console`, then `Python Console`, check the `add content roots to PYTHONPATH option`.

Comment: Looks like that one way already enabled by default and was adding the project root folders. Add source roots to PYTHONPATH is actually what I was looking for. This solved it for me though. Thanks!